# My SQL query is not optimised neither it looks good, please have a look

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table called m_techno_idea(stores ideas), m_techno_idea_moderator_vote(moderator votes), and m_techno_idea_user_vote(for uservotes). User vote is only 1 while moderator vote is between 1 -5 and is stored in the column named votes. So I need to get the total no. of votes in a single query. I don't want a nested query.

My Attempts:

**Attempt 1:**

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT TIUV.PK_ID) + IFNULL((SUM(TIMV.VOTES)),0) AS VOTES
  FROM 
        M_TECHNO_IDEA TI 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        M_TECHNO_IDEA_MODERATOR_VOTE TIMV
   ON 
       TIMV.FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID=TI.PK_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
       M_TECHNO_IDEA_USER_VOTE TIUV
  ON
       TIUV.FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID=TI.PK_ID
  WHERE 
       TI.PK_ID=2
```

Here distinct keyword helps me to have distinct rows for user votes but for moderator votes I can't use distinct, as the votes can be same in many rows.This gives me wrong results.

**Attempt 2:**

```
SELECT (select count(TIUV.PK_ID) FROM M_TECHNO_IDEA_USER_VOTE TIUV
WHERE TIUV.FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID=2) +
(select sum(TIMV.VOTES) FROM M_TECHNO_IDEA_moderator_VOTE TIMV
WHERE TIMV.FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID=2) AS VOTES
```

Attempt 2 gives me correct results but the query doesn't look good. I have tried group by also but it didn't help me too. Any Help will be appreciated.

**Attempt 3:**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT TIUV.PK_ID) + IFNULL(MODVOTES.VOTES, 0) AS VOTES
FROM
    (SELECT 
        TIMV.FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID, SUM(TIMV.VOTES) VOTES
    FROM
        M_TECHNO_IDEA_MODERATOR_VOTE TIMV
    GROUP BY TIMV.FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID) MODVOTES
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    M_TECHNO_IDEA_USER_VOTE TIUV ON TIUV.FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID = MODVOTES.FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID
WHERE
    TIUV.FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID = 2
```

This attempt also gives me the correct result. I had to place a nested sub query. If a better solution comes, it would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why are you using left joins to do so?

Comment: @DanBracuk: My problem is that I want to use a single query, and I wish to avoid nested query. I simply want to get the sum of two votes stored in two different tables, user vote by counting the number of entries and moderator vote by adding all the rows of the column votes.

Comment: Without seeing the `EXPLAIN` output, it's impossible to gauge the relative performance.  I don't what you mean by "the query doesn't look good".

Comment: I wish to avoid using two many selects and sub queries, so I opted for join, but the problem I faced is join creates some duplicate rows, for the user votes I used distinct to avoid it but for the moderator votes I am confused, how to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, "I simply want to get the sum of two votes stored in two different tables", use a derived table.  Here is the general idea.

```
select sum(votes) totalvotes
from (
select count(something) votes
from TheFirstTable
where whatever
union 
select count(something) votes
from TheSecondTable
where whatever ) ThisIsCalledADerivedTable
```

You can put together the derived table to suit your requirements.

Comment: better hope the counts from the two tables are not the same... union eliminates duplicates!

Comment: I know.  This is a general idea.

Comment: OK, maybe you don't know. Change `union` to `union all`, which does *not* remove duplicates. Then your query will work correctly.

Comment: Typically, you'd add another "label" column indicating the source of the summation.

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is good, except you can clean it up a lot by removing unnecessary aliases, using consistent letter-casing and a little formatting:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM M_TECHNO_IDEA_USER_VOTE WHERE FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID = 2) +
    (SELECT SUM(VOTES) FROM M_TECHNO_IDEA_moderator_VOTE WHERE FK_TECHNO_IDEA_ID = 2)
AS VOTES
```

Comment: In my first attempt, is there something of this sort that would let me have distinct votes.

           "SUM(TIMV.VOTES) OVER DISTINCT TIMV.PK_ID"

I mean I can't use SUM(DISTINCT TIMV.VOTES) as it is not what I want.

Comment: Do you want the total votes for each PK_ID, which is shared across the two tables? In other words, two columns: `pk_id, votes` in the output?

Comment: The fields in the user votes table are pk_id,fk_techno_idea_id,fk_user_id, votes, voted_on

and moderator votes table are: pk_id,fk_techno_idea_id,fk_user_id,voted_on

:::::"fk_techno_idea_id is common in these."